# local variable might be referenced before assignment error while using Python's argparse library. Need help debugging

Tags: python, debugging, ssh, reference, argparse

I am currently receiving an error that states: "local variable might be referenced before assignment" for three variables, deviceIP, deviceUsername, and devicePassword. These arguments are added using the arparse library and I'm not too familiar with the fact on why I'm receiving these errors.

I am assuming that these variable values are entered using the command line and I've tried to enter them in the command line but with no success because my program is not compiling. Here is the code:

```
#usage: ....py [-h] 
#           [-deviceIP DEVICEIP]
#                       [-deviceUsername DEVICEUSERNAME]
#                       [-devicePassword DEVICEPASSWORD]

def Main():
    # Initialize dynamic time stamp and script name
    beginstamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
    beginDisplayedstamp = getStamp()
    scriptName = os.path.basename(__file__)

    print (" scriptName = ", scriptName)
    scriptPurpose = 'Script to reboot swtich.\n'

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=scriptPurpose, formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("-deviceIP", help="Target device IP address", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-deviceUsername", help="Target device username", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-devicePassword", help="Target device password", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #Section to handle the input parameters
    if args.deviceIP is None:
        line = "Fail, The deviceIP parameter is blank.\n"
        print (line)

    else:
        deviceIP = args.deviceIP

    if args.deviceUsername is None:
        line = "Fail, The deviceUsername parameter is blank.\n"
        print (line)
    else:
        deviceUsername = args.deviceUsername

    if args.devicePassword is None:
        line = "Fail, The devicePassword parameter is blank.\n"
        print (line)
    else:
        devicePassword = args.devicePassword

    print ("**********************")
    print (deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword)

    print ("Checking the connectivity of the device\n"

    ret = ping(deviceIP)
    ret = 1
    #print ret

    if ret:
        print ("DeviceIP is pingabale continue")
    else:
        print ("Device IP not accessible, Give valid IP")

    sys.exit(-1)
```

Here are the error codes when I run the program but maybe I'm getting this because I'm not sure on how to enter these arguments correctly ?

```
C:/......
 scriptName =  Cisco_switch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
Fail, The deviceIP parameter is blank.

  File "C:/.....", line 280, in <module>
Fail, The deviceUsername parameter is blank.
    Main()

  File "C:/......", line 225, in Main
Fail, The devicePassword parameter is blank.
    print(deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'deviceIP' referenced before assignment
**********************

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: You only set the variable `deviceIP` when `args.deviceIP` is not `None`. But later you print it whether or not it was set. You should either give it a default value or return if a required argument isn't given.

Comment: The same with all the other arguments.

Comment: What commandline are you using?  What do you expect your code to do when you don't provide an argument like `deviceIP`.  The default is `None`, which check for, but don't do anything about.